# Does windows have some inbuilt database engine?

Tags: c#, windows

So far, in my applications, I stored all my data via serialization, so I never really needed anything else. But now I am working with more complicated data and I need more than a simple file to store them. Is there some inbuilt storage engine in Windows I can use, which will allow me to pull and edit data with SQL queries? (Since I doubt the user will be willing to install and configure standalone MySQL server just for my application and I don't really want to use 3rd party solutions)
And if there is, how can I access such database engine?

Comment: Just install expres edtion of MsSQL server. This is free

Comment: I hear great things about http://www.sqlite.org/  It's not embedded within Windows, but you could check it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Windows does have an embedded database engine, which has been there since Windows 2000. It is called [Esent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Storage_Engine).

There is a project called [Managed Esent](https://github.com/microsoft/managedesent) to expose the features of Esent to managed code. There is a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Database.ManagedEsent/) for it.

I do not know whether it fits your exact need of updates via SQL queries but it does boast a number of features:

- ACID transactions with savepoints, lazy commits, and robust crash recovery.
- Snapshot isolation.
- Highly concurrent database access.
- Flexible meta-data (tens of thousands of columns, tables, and indexes are possible).
- Indexing support for integer, floating point, ASCII, Unicode, and binary columns.

**Update**
I have since had some experience with Esent in C# via the nuget package. It does NOT have SQL query capabilities. There is support for indices and basic cursors over them but nothing like the power of SQL. My suggestion if you need a light-weight SQL is definitely SQLite.

Comment: Microsoft has documentation online about Extensible Storage Engine at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/extensible-storage-engine/extensible-storage-engine

Comment: Here is an article that provides a simple example of using ESE and the API for it.  https://www.codeproject.com/articles/52715/extensible-storage-engine as well as this old article with Visual Basic examples https://emmet-gray.com/Articles/ESE.html and the GitHub for ESENT Managed Interop https://github.com/microsoft/managedesent

Answer (score 2):

SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine.

http://www.sqlite.org

SQLite will work without requiring your App User to install SQLExpress or any other database engine, making it a good option for desktop applications.

Answer (score 2):

Use SQLite as standalone database and integrated part of your applications. 
Main benefits:

- data is stored inside a single file, easy to pull/edit
- ships as part of your application as dll, no separate
  installation/configuration needed

Answer (score 0):

i found some info about the database on the Microsoft website [database info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269259%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx)
there is a embedded database engine. [Esent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Storage_Engine)

Comment: "Enter a more descriptive answer here" - Just don't post an answer with only a link.. Links dissapear

Answer (score -2):

If it is small set of user specific data, storing at windows registry is a good option.

Comment: Nope, large table of data.

Answer (score -2):

No, there is no inbuilt database available.
But there are good alternatives, like the mqsql express server or a SQLITE database, which is basically a single database file which is accessed through a library in your project. So if you use SQLITE, you do not need to instal anything.